# How do I measure which links get the most clicks?

Tags: links, analytics, statistics

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how I can measure which types of links (links to twitter [or other social network] profiles, links to videos, stack exchange flair, navigational menus, etc.) are being clicked on the most.

What's a simple way to measure what links are being clicked on my site, and optionally by what demographic?

Comment: I'm taking the liberty of generalizing this question to make it more workable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you have links on your website, and you want to be able to track the outgoing links on your site (links that connect to a site other than yours). I'm sure there are scripts/software you can find to handle this, and the idea would be along the lines of this:

Rather than linking "Twitter.com/Username" you could have "YourSite.com/Links.php?id=1". The script you write (or find) would know that id=1 means it should send the viewer to "Twitter.com/Username", but before it does this, it will add +1 to the hits, and log IP/browser/hostname/etc. Then you could create a backend page that lets you view the results.

I'm sure there are scripts that do this for you (and I believe Google Analytics has a way to implement this functionality). A quick Google search would definitely yield you some results on the subject. Hope this helps.